# How to explicitly add a project to the Python path in CircleCI 2.0?

Tags: python, django, pytest, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm unsure how to set the PYTHONPATH correctly in CircleCI 2.0 to allow the build to run.  This is a Django project that was previously building on CircleCI 1.0 successfully so I've started by using the auto generated config.yml file.

```
version: 2
  jobs:
    build:
      working_directory: ~/mygithubname/myproject
      parallelism: 1
      shell: /bin/bash --login

environment:
  CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
  CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results
  DATABASE_URL: 'sqlite://:memory:'
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: myproject.settings.test
  DEBUG: 0
  PYTHONPATH: ${HOME}/myproject/myproject

docker:
- image: circleci/build-image:ubuntu-14.04-XXL-upstart-1189-5614f37
  command: /sbin/init
steps:

- checkout

- run: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS

- restore_cache:
    keys:
    # This branch if available
    - v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-
    # Default branch if not
    - v1-dep-master-
    # Any branch if there are none on the default branch - this should be unnecessary if you have your default branch configured correctly
    - v1-dep-
- run: pip install -r requirements/testing.txt

- save_cache:
    key: v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
    paths:
    # This is a broad list of cache paths to include many possible development environments
    # You can probably delete some of these entries
    - vendor/bundle
    - ~/virtualenvs
    - ~/.m2
    - ~/.ivy2
    - ~/.bundle
    - ~/.go_workspace
    - ~/.gradle
    - ~/.cache/bower

- run: pytest

- store_test_results:
    path: /tmp/circleci-test-results

- store_artifacts:
    path: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
- store_artifacts:
    path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
```

The `run: pytest` command is failing in CircleCI with the error stating `pytest-django could not find a Django project (no manage.py file could be found). You must explicitly add your Django project to the Python path to have it picked up.`  I know what the error means but not sure how to fix in version 2 (it works when building on version 1), and I'm struggling to find anything in the documents.

Comment: Your working directory has your GitHub name in it but your python path does not. Is that intentional?

Comment: That's where I think the problem may be - as it stands above the working directory is what was auto generated by the CircleCI config generator; the Python path is taken from the original config file (and was placed in this file by the auto generator). Not intentional as such!

Comment: It's been been a while since I've done any Django, but I'd try setting your PYTHONPATH to ${HOME}/mygithubname/myproject/myproject

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that, but same error unfortunately

Comment: One last thought - maybe remove the second myproject: ${HOME}/mygithubname/myproject as the PYTHONPATH, I vaguely recall something about  django changing the nesting python path in a later version.

Comment: Already tried that - pus a few variations. Hoping someone will have come across this!

Comment: Try adding a new `run` step to do an `echo $PYTHONPATH`. I seem to have a recollection that `environment` entries cannot be defined in terms of other variables.

Comment: More importantly though, most of your YAML file is wrongly indented - it is important to understand the data structure that Circle 2.0 needs. Most of that stuff (`environment` on down) are keys of `build`, so all that needs to be indented. [See the reference doc](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/).

Comment: The indent was just a copy and paste issue! It's correct in the actual file.  I'd already tried the `echo $PYTHONPATH` suggestion, but in the end solved it by adding a command to `cd` into the folder where the pytest command should run

Answer (score 1):

In circleci environment variables can't be used with expansion
you need to either use `BASH_ENV` https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#using-bash_env-to-set-environment-variables

```
- run: echo 'export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/myproject/folder_with_manage.py:${HOME}/myproject/folder_with_tests"' >> $BASH_ENV
```

Or set proper paths manually, add project folder and folder with manage.py and folder with tests

```
environment:
  PYTHONPATH: /root/myproject/:/root/myproject/folder_with_manage.py/:/root/myproject/folder_with_tests/
```

To check that it is working you could do

```
- run: echo $PYTHONPATH
```

or

```
- run: python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

If you are using image without bash do not forget to do https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-shell-command

```
source $BASH_ENV
# run tests
```